# Fondue without Gruyere cheese

Tags: substitutions, cheese, fondue

Can you give me some good tips how to prepare Fondue without Gruyere/Raclete cheese? What are possible substitutes, and what should I pay attention to when substituting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a true Fondue but I've done something very similar by taking a white sauce base made with 50 / 50 wine and milk. You then melt in lots and lots of cheese and you get something very nice and similar to a fondue. You can pretty much use any reasonably melting cheese you like although a strong cheddar is very nice. For something really interesting add some Mozzerella and slowly melt it down and you get a wonderful stringy finish.

Answer (score 6):

Vacherin, Comté or Emmental,

I wouldn't go for Gouda, it's not cheese from the fondue regions. But it's maybe worth an experiment ;)

Don't forget you can mix cheeses, 1/2 Gruyere and 1/2 Emmental for example,

Comment: +1 In Switzerland we have death penalty on putting Gouda, Cheddar an the likes in a fondue!

Comment: Gouda gives a creamy flavour to Fondue. Don't be dogmatic. :-)

Comment: I've had good fondue with gouda and/or cheddar. Gouda is more an 'additive' than a fondue base, though (imho).

Answer (score 5):

In New Zealand we made fondue moitié-moitié with mild white Cheddar and Gouda. Very creamy. I think you can make fondue with almost any meltable pure and good cheese, if the original ingredients are unobtainable. More important is the dry wine, a little starch, garlic and pepper. A shot of a good hard liquor also adds flavor. Kirsch (cherry schnapps) is best, but good whisky or cognac also works.

If the wine is not dry enough, give a spoon of lemon juice or even vinegar (!). The acid helps the blending. If the cheese separates, dissolve a tea-spoon starch in the liquor and reheat carefully stirring continuously.

Gouda and Cheddar also work for Raclette.

NB: we are Swiss and not dogmatic at all! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Two more tips for good fondue's I've made without gruyere:

1. Spicy fondue with ginger
2. Blue cheese fondue (generally made a but softer with mascarpone) & white wine. Excellent for dipping dark brown bread and grapes.

Answer (score 2):

Try fontina and truffles for an Italian Alpine fondue.

Answer (score 1):

2/3 Brick, 1/3 Emmental. Add a pinch of fresh parmesan for more taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take the standard Swiss fondue recipe moitié-moitié and use all Emmental instead of 1/2 Gruyere and 1/2 Emmental. This came in handy when looking for a way to make fondue for a person who needs to avoid all dairy products from cow and goat milk. In Switzerland, I was lucky enough to find sheep Emmental. I'm not Swiss but I was happy with the result :)